# Grunt bower_concat not adding css

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, bower

I try to compile all my css from my bower_components using bower_concat https://github.com/sapegin/grunt-bower-concat. The js compiles fine but the css never gets created. Here is my grunt file code for this section:

```
  bower_concat: {
            all: {
                dest: '<%= pkg.dist_dir %>/lib/_bower.js',
                cssDest: '<%= pkg.dist_dir %>/lib/_bower.css',
                dependencies: {
                    // 'angular': ''
                },
                exclude: [
                    'jquery'
                ],
                bowerOptions: {
                    relative: false
                },
                includeDev: true
            }
        },
```

It never creates "_bower.css". Why is not working as it should?

Comment: I'm having the same problem (I'm totally new to grunt and bower.) Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: So I ended up rewriting my Gruntfile from scratch I will post it as an answer to see if it helps you.

Comment: see my answer and LMK if it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[grunt-bower-concat](https://github.com/sapegin/grunt-bower-concat) (and [grunt-wiredep](https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-wiredep) as well) work on the concept of bundling together files mentioned in the `main` field of the bower.json of the respective package.

Initially there wasn't any specification which defined what should be included in `main` field of the bower.json file. It was solely up to the package creator to make this choice. Then [Define main as the entry-point files, one-per-filetype](https://github.com/bower/spec/pull/43) came (This lead to known libraries like [Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/16359) and [Font Awesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/commit/7cde41ea934f43e66dc123ea6411d8535b50a4f7) removing the CSS files from `main` field, rendering tools like grunt-bower-concat  useless without manual override)

```
mainFiles: {
    package: [ 'path/to/its/file.css' ]
}
```

Therefore a probable cause of the issue you are facing would be related to the fact that the `main` field of the bower package that you trying to include doesn't reference the CSS files.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it according to the [config example](https://github.com/sapegin/grunt-bower-concat#config-example) at the bottom of the page, that is instead adding the destinations in the all parameter, creating the dest parameter and setting js/css destinations individually:

```
bower_concat: {
  all: {
    dest: {
      'js': 'build/_bower.js',
      'css': 'build/_bower.css'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of release 1.0.0, there is a new API and cssDest has been removed:

```
Concatenation of any file types

The new API looks like this:

bower_concat: {
    main: {
        dest: {
            js: 'build/_bower.js',
            scss: 'build/_bower.scss',
            coffee: 'build/_bower.coffee'
        },
        // ...
    }
}
The old dest as a string ({dest: 'build/_bower.js'}) is still working but the cssDest was removed.
```

See release notes [here](https://github.com/sapegin/grunt-bower-concat/releases).

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was missing one files in the css directory

1. pkg.name.less (This needs to match the package name defined in
   package.json) and needs to contains this: @import "auto_imports.less";

This basically includes the include auto generated by my grunt file (auto_imports.less) which has a bunch of includes (each .less file you might have in your app)
And auto_imports.less

And also I needed to run this:

```
bower:        {
    install: {
        options: {
            cleanTargetDir: true,
            targetDir:      '<%= pkg.dist_dir %>/lib'
        }
    }
},
```

Before **bower_concat** so that it can get all the 3rd party libraries, and that is why bower_concat was not working for me at least for the css. I ended up re-writing the whole Gruntfile so if copy it, it should work fine. I made a template out of it for my future project lol

Here is the full Gruntfile.js, hopefully it makes sense when you look at it

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
    grunt.initConfig({
        //define pkg object and point to package.json
        pkg:          grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        //define notifications
        notify_hooks: {
            options: {
                enabled:                  true,
                max_jshint_notifications: 5, // maximum number of notifications from jshint output
                title:                    "<%= pkg.name %>", // defaults to the name in package.json, or will use project directory's name
                success:                  false, // whether successful grunt executions should be notified automatically
                duration:                 3 // the duration of notification in seconds, for `notify-send only
            }
        },
        notify:       {
            build: {
                options: {
                    title:   '<%= pkg.name %> Build',
                    message: 'Build Completed'
                }
            },
            js:    {
                options: {
                    message: 'Completed JS Build'
                }
            },
            css:   {
                options: {
                    message: 'Completed CSS Build'
                }
            },
            bower: {
                options: {
                    message: 'Completed Bower'
                }
            }
        },
        //define clean task
        clean:        {
            bower: ["<%= bower.install.options.targetDir %>", "bower_components"]
        },
        //define bower task
        bower:        {
            install: {
                options: {
                    cleanTargetDir: true,
                    targetDir:      '<%= pkg.dist_dir %>/lib'
                }
            }
        },
        bower_concat: {
            all: {
                dest:         '<%= pkg.dist_dir %>/lib/_bower.js',
                cssDest:      '<%= pkg.dist_dir %>/lib/_bower.css',
                bowerOptions: {
                    relative: false
                },
                dependencies: {
                    'angular':    ['jquery', 'moment'],
                    'datePicker': ['moment']
                },
                mainFiles: {
                  'ng-flags': 'src/directives/ng-flags.js'
                },
                includeDev:   true
            }
        },
        //define concat task to concat all js files
        concat:       {
            js: {
                options: {
                    separator: '\n'
                },
                src:     [
                    'js/app/app.js', 'js/**/*.js'
                ],
                dest:    '<%= pkg.dist_dir %>/<%= pkg.name %>.js'
            }
        },
        uglify:       {
            options: {
                banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("dd-mm-yyyy") %> */\n',
                mangle: false
            },
            js:      {
                files: {
                    '<%= pkg.dist_dir %>/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js': ['<%= concat.js.dest %>']
                }
            }
        },
        jshint:       {
            files:   ['Gruntfile.js', 'js/**/*.js', '!js/lib/*.js'],
            options: {
                globals: {
                    jQuery:  true,
                    console: true,
                    module:  true
                }
            }
        },
        //define less task
        less:         {
            all: {
                options: {
                    paths: ["css"]
                },
                files:   {
                    "<%= pkg.dist_dir %>/<%= pkg.name %>.css": "css/<%= pkg.name %>.less"
                }
            }
        },
        less_imports: {
            options: {
                inlineCSS: false
            },
            all:     {
                src:  [ 'css/**/*.less', '!<%= less_imports.all.dest %>', '!css/<%= pkg.name %>.less'],
                dest: 'css/auto_imports.less'
            }
        },
        //define the watch task. (documented at https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch)
        watch:        {
            js:         {
                files: ['<%= concat.js.src %>'],
                tasks: ['build_js']
            },
            css:        {
                files: ['css/**/*.less'],
                tasks: ['build_css']
            },
            grunt_file: {
                files: ['Gruntfile.js'],
                tasks: ['build']
            }
        }
    });

    //bower tasks
    grunt.registerTask('bower_install', [ 'clean:bower', 'bower', 'bower_concat', 'notify:bower']);

    grunt.registerTask('build_css', ['less_imports', 'less', 'notify:css']);
    grunt.registerTask('build_js', ['jshint', 'concat:js', 'uglify:js', 'notify:js']);

    // the default task can be run just by typing "grunt" on the command line
    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'bower_install', 'build_css', 'build_js'
    ]);
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['build']);

    // Start the notification task.
    grunt.task.run('notify_hooks');

};
```

Comment: I also added watch so that it only compiles the files I am working on and not all 3rd parties it makes it run faster